# A fetal error occurred processing the restoration data

Tags: windows, windows-10, hibernate, reboot, windows-installation

Today when I tried to start my computer from hibernation, it stucked on windows log, so I shouted down the computer by pressing the power button and then when I tried to start it again the recovery error page appeared contained the (A fetal error occurred processing the restoration data)
File:hiberfil.sys
I searched for solution for solving this problem on the internet and the solution seems to be accessing the cmd and then turn off the hibernation mode and restart the computer then deleting the hibernation file and turning it on again.
But now my problem is that, when I press the F8 key to enter into Startup setting to access the cmd, the error page appears again and again, and there is no way for me to access the cmd.
The op system is windows 10
I will appreciate any help.
Thank you

Comment: Abort, get a bootable disk and run chkdsk

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75, is abort allowed on a fetal error?

Comment: Only in a liberal society